# How to get automatically created Javascript variable in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to overcome an issue with using a Google login API in react.

The issue is caused by the user already having a logged in session, meaning the API isn't needed and can be ignored. The solution in **Javascript** looks like this:

```
const auth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

if (!auth.isSignedIn.get()) {
   auth.signIn().then(() => 
        // Do login stuff
    );
} else {
   // Get old signIn data
}
```

The problem here is in the first line. The `gapi` variable is created after an automatic call to the Google login API. Dynamic typing seems to be useful here, because it just finds `gapi` as required.

Problem is I'm using **Typescript**, so the above code needs to have hard typing. It's therefore giving an error:

`Error: (TS) Cannot find name 'gapi'`

How can I tell Typescript that gapi will exist?

I've had similar before with values that could be null, which I overcome via

```
if(value == null){
    //do nothing
} else {
    //use the value;
    }
```

but the problem here is that I'd be saying `if(gapi == null)` which still gives the `Cannot find name gapi` error.

Is there a know workaround for telling Typescript that it's going to be looking for and using a javascript variable created by an external source/API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `@types/gapi` type definitions which will add `gapi` with type safety to the global namespace.

You can also simply declare `gapi` in the global namespace yourself. For example:

```
declare const gapi: any;
```

However, this won't give you type safety. You could add your own type definitions if you saw fit, but `@types/gapi` has essentially done this for you.

---

I wouldn't recommend it, but it can be handy in some cases to use `// @ts-ignore` comments to skip over type checking on the next line. You could do this above a line where `gapi` is used, but the above solutions should work a lot better.

Comment: This answer has fewer votes but I think it's much more informative. There are times when `@types` are unavailable in Typescript, so your broader solution to declare globally as `any` is much better. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need the `@types` of `gapi` run `npm i -D @types/gapi` to install it.